# Get other MIME Parts using the Extended Property API

Tags: outlook-restapi

According to [this API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/extended-properties-rest-operations), you can request various MAPI properties from the message. I need to get other MIME parts of a message, specifically the `message/delivery-status` part.

Are there any extended properties that can get me this information? I've tried a few, but none seem to really give me what I need. It looks like [this would](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200514(v=exchg.80).aspx), but I can't seem to get that to work with the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - it looks like I could get the information I am after with the `PR_SUPPLEMENTARY_INFO_W` tag.

Unfortunately, it looks like the API currently does not support some MAPI tags. For example, `PR_SUPPLEMENTARY_INFO_W` seems to be accepted, but there is no `SingleValueExtendedProperty` in what is returned. Maybe this will change once the API is out of beta.